# Filtrar productos por categoria en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estoy aprendiendo php (soy bastante nuevo) y he estado haciendo algunos ejercicios, estoy creando una sección donde se muestran todas las categorías, pero no logro que me muestre las imágenes que corresponden a cada categoría, si no que en cada categoría me muestra todas las imágenes de la tabla, tengo 2 tablas, una con el nombre de la categoría y su id que se llama nombrecategorias, y otra que se llama empresa con el id de la categoría a la que pertenece, el id de la imagen y su nombre
En esta primera parte del codigo preparo y ejecuto las consultas

```
$conexion = conexion('categorias', 'root','');


if(!$conexion){
die();
}
$statement = $conexion->prepare("
SELECT * FROM nombrecategorias ");

$statement->execute();
$categorias=$statement->fetchAll();

if (!$categorias) {
header('Location:index.php');
}

$statement = $conexion->prepare("
SELECT * FROM empresa ");
$statement->execute();
$empresas=$statement->fetchAll();

$statement = $conexion->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM nombrecategorias INNER JOIN empresa ON nombrecategorias.id=empresa.idcategoria ");

 $statement->execute();
 $categoriasid=$statement->fetchAll();

 print_r($categoriasid);
    require 'directorio.view.php';
 ?>
```

En esta segunda parte es donde estoy teniendo el problema

```
 <?php foreach($categoriasid as $categoriaid):?>

 <?php if ($_GET['id']=$categoriaid['id']):?>

 <div class="logo-directorio col-md-3">
 <a href="directorio-empresa.php?id=<?php echo $categoriaid['idcategoria'];?
 >">

 <img src="images/logosempresas/<?php echo $categoriaid['logoempresa']; ?>" alt="">
                            </a>
 </div>
<?php endif?>


<?php endforeach?>
```

Me carga las imagenes desde la base de datos, pero las carga todas en todas las categorías y no solo las que deben ser por cada categoría, espero puedan ayudarme, si estoy realizando la consulta mal o algo en el código o pueden darme consejos, se los agradeceré bastante, de antemano gracias

Comment: En el if te falta un `=` es de decir deberia ser `==`.Por otro lado seria mejor que filtraras la categoria directamente en la consulta, en lugar de traer todas las categorias si no las va a utilizar.

Comment: No termino de entender tu código, ni lo que quieres hacer. Cuando planteas la pregunta al principio dices que quieres todas las categorías, luego dices que el problema es que carga todas las categorías. O sea, ***¿lo que quieres se convierte a la vez en tu problema?***.  ¿No será que quieres todas las categorías, pero en un cierto orden? Sería bueno que pongas un ejemplo del resultado esperado. Lo que sí aparece claro es que tu código necesita ser optimizado. ¿Por qué tienes tres `SELECT`? **Tu último `SELECT` te trae los datos de ambas tablas, no necesitas seleccionarlos por separado.**

Answer (score 1):

**Primero**: en el bucle

```
 <?php if ($_GET['id']=$categoriaid['id']):?>

 <div class="logo-directorio col-md-3">
 <a href="directorio-empresa.php?id=<?php echo $categoriaid['idcategoria'];?
 >">

 <img src="images/logosempresas/<?php echo $categoriaid['logoempresa']; ?>" alt="">
                            </a>
 </div>
<?php endif?>
```

Estás haciendo una ssignación (y siempre es true):

```
if ($_GET['id']=$categoriaid['id'])
```

Cuando debiera ser una comparación

```
if ($_GET['id'] == $categoriaid['id'])
```

**Segundo**: mezclar bloques `if` al estilo `if(): .... endif` con bloques `if() { ... }` es confuso y difícil de debuggear. Yo preferiría ser consistente con los estilos de los bloques y usar siempre {...} aprovechando que los editores te marcan qué llave se cierra con cuál.

**Tercero**: si tienes el ID de categoría por parámetro $_GET, podrías filtrar en la consulta:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$statement = $conexion->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM nombrecategorias INNER JOIN empresa ON nombrecategorias.id=empresa.idcategoria WHERE idcategoria=:id");
$statement->bindValue(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$categoriasid=$statement->fetchAll();
```

Y ahorrarte la comparación en el bucle final